# localhost page took to long to respond

Tags: mysql, xampp, localhost

My XAMPP took to long to respond due to large result of sql query. My query result return approximately 1400 rows. Is that why my local page keep loading? If so, what should I do to fix this? There is no syntax error..

```
    public function promotion()
{

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('booking');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data['result'] = $query->result_array();

    $this->load->view('admin/promotion',$data);
}
```

My view :

```
        <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($result as $r) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $r['booking_date'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $r['from_email'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $r['vendor_airway_bill'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $r['max_tariff'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $r['status'];?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
```

I am using xampp v3.2.2, phpmyadmin, on windows 10 64bit

Comment: 1. What exactly does it mean that the page loaded slowly? How many seconds? 2. There is not too much point in displaying 1400 records anyway on a screen. Use paging and filtering to display a portion of relevant bookings only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be better, if you load only a part of your data (e.g. like in online shops where only 25 products are shown). Another way would be loading the content time by time (e.g. with AJAX and JavaScript)?